# 2sxc9.32.0 error with Content Module

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

DNN: 8.0.4
2sxc: 9.32.0

This is an upgrade to 8.0.4 from an earlier version, but the site is running with no problems.

I added a Content module to a page and selected the "Title Over Image" content item.  I get this error:

Error: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name: 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' at Connect.Dnn.Koi.DnnSkinFile.AutoDetect() at Connect.Koi.Context.HttpContextState.TryToDetectTheCssFramework() at Connect.Koi.Context.HttpContextState.get_CssFramework() at Connect.Koi.Context.ToolsForCurrentState.get_Css() at Connect.Koi.Koi.get_IsUnknown() at ASP._Page_Portals_781_2sxc_Content__Shared___Koi_Admin_Messages_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\vhosts\dev.patapscoresearch.com\httpdocs\Portals\781\2sxc\Content_Shared - Koi Admin Messages.cshtml:line 8 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6(TextWriter writer) at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) at ASP._Page_Portals_781_2sxc_Content__Shared___Assets_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\vhosts\dev.patapscoresearch.com\httpdocs\Portals\781\2sxc\Content_Shared - Assets.cshtml:line 2 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6(TextWriter writer) at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) at ASP._Page_Portals_781_2sxc_Content__Content___Image_full_width_text_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\vhosts\dev.patapscoresearch.com\httpdocs\Portals\781\2sxc\Content_Content - Image full-width text.cshtml:line 4 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.RazorEngine.Render(TextWriter writer) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy Content Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 65 at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.RazorEngine.RenderTemplate() in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy Content Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 92 at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.EngineBase.Render() in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\SexyContent\Engines\EngineBase.cs:line 92 at ToSic.SexyContent.SxcInstance.Render() in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\SexyContent\SxcInstance_Render.cs:line 58 WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: There is a System.Web.Helpers.dll file in the bin directory: version 3.0.20129.0

Answer (score 1):

Check your web.config for empty xmlns tags like: 
`<assemblyBinding xmlns="">`

And remove them, like:
`<assemblyBinding>`

That worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that for some unclear reason, you're missing a web.config in the folder structure. Best compare it with a working setup - you should see a web.config in the portals/x/2sxc folder. I think that should fix it.

This was also asked in https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1595 and there a solution was found. pls check that.